# Error while updating google event

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to update google calendar event but it is not working with default calendar .. i mean when i use 'primary' default calendar it is not working 
this is my code

```html
const USER_EVENT_TYPE='primary';
const CLASS_EVENTS='Events';
 if ($googleClient->getAccessToken())
        {
            if(!class_exists(self::CLASS_EVENTS))
            {
                $includeApplicationFiles=Mage::getBaseDir(self::LIBRARY_PATH);
                foreach (glob($includeApplicationFiles.self::INCLUDE_ALL_FILES) as $retrieveFiles)
                {
                    include $retrieveFiles;
                }
                $allCalendarEvents = $googleCalendar->events->listEvents(self::USER_EVENT_TYPE);
                foreach ($allCalendarEvents->getItems() as $getSingleEvent) {
                    if($selectedEventValue==$getSingleEvent->summary)
                    {
                        $getSingleEvent->setSummary($selectedEventValue);
                        $addEventGuests = new Google_EventAttendee();
                        $addEventGuests->setEmail($selectGuestValue);
                        $invitedGuests = array($addEventGuests);
                        $getSingleEvent->attendees = $invitedGuests;
                        $updatedEvent = $googleCalendar->events->update(self::USER_EVENT_TYPE, $getSingleEvent->getId(),$getSingleEvent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Having error like this

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/5vmet3i6mmak81utnj2p0ebv8g?key=900220817963%40developer.gserviceaccount.com: (403) Forbidden' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php(35): Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php(152): Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_CalendarService.php(591): Google_ServiceResource-&gt;__call('update', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Social\Google\Model\Google.php(360): Google_EventsServiceResource-&gt;update('primary', '5vmet3i6mmak81u...', Object(Google_Event))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\Connectors\google\AutoCompleteCalendarEvents.php(16): Social_Goog in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php</b> on line <b>61</b><br />
```

Comment: (403) Forbidden:  Something is wrong with your authentication you don't have access if you are seeing that.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all your code I would make two suggestions:

You can update your key and check your settings in the developer console. If you have changed your project namespace and used the same key, you can have problems.

The other thing is if you have set your developer key anywhere to delete that:

```
$googleClient->setDeveloperKey('insert_key');
```

If you have a read through the following link, it shows a range of similar problems.

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/issues/detail?id=218

I should add, that `403 Forbidden` indicates that you are communicating with the server successfully, but you lack permission for that action/operation.
Which is why it leans towards:
1. the key being invalid, or
2. if the key is valid, and you have overridden the valid key value in  your code.   Thus presenting a new value, which (of course) is an invalid key.

Let me know if you need more help.